# MS Query - Calculate the Mode on more than 1 field

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

Using MS Query, the following code works, it finds the Mode for "Sales Price" and displays it in Excel 2007.

```
(Connection code here has been omitted)
SELECT TOP 1 "Sales Price" AS "SPrice Mode", COUNT(*) Frequency
FROM "Sales Table" WHERE ("Date of Sale" BETWEEN ? AND ?) AND (City LIKE ?)
GROUP BY "Sales Price"
ORDER BY Frequency DESC 
Enter Start Date        Enter END Date  Enter City
```

I would like to modify this query so that it will also find the Mode for 2 other fields, "Price per Unit" and "Price per SF", both are in the same "Sales Table" as is "Sales Price".  Also, I want the user to only have to enter the parameters once.  After searching the Net, I have not been able to find a solution.  I've tried variations using UNION and JOIN, but to no avail.  Any help or guidance would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by "Mode"?

Comment: The statistical Mode, which is the number that occurs most frequently.  For example, in the list (1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4) the number "2" would be the Mode with a frequency of 4.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the modes for multiple columns using window functions.  In the following query, the innermost query calculates the count for each value.  The next subquery gets the maximum count, and the outermost query gets the values of the variables at the maximum count:

```
select max(case when cnt_sp = max_cnt_sp then "Sales Price" end) as mod_Sales_Price,
       max(case when cnt_ppu = max_cnt_ppu then "Price Per Unit" end) as mod_Price_Per_Unit,
       max(case when cnt_ppsf = max_cnt_ppsf then "Price Per SF" end) as mod_Price_Per_SF       
from (select st.*,
             max(cnt_sp) over () as max_cnt_sp,
             max(cnt_ppu) over () as max_cnt_ppu,
             max(cnt_ppsf) over () as max_cnt_ppsf
      from (select st.*,
                   count(*) over (partition by "Sales Price") as cnt_sp,
                   count(*) over (partition by "Price Per Unit") as cnt_ppu,
                   count(*) over (partition by "Price Per SF") as cnt_ppsf
            from "Sales Table" st
           ) st
     ) st
```